Retrieve fist date in the list that is more recent than today
We're trying to find the first date in a list that is more recent than today.
Sheet InvoicingPeriods
----------------------
27/05/2024
24/06/2024
22/07/2024
19/08/2024
16/09/2024

Given that =TODAY() is 07/08/2024 we would like to find date 19/08/2024 in the list above, as it is the first match.
We're not really Google Sheets experts, and tried some examples online, but we couldn't figure it out. Thank you for your help.
Here is a Test sheet with example data.


You may try:
=let(Σ,InvoicingPeriods!A:A,xlookup(today()+1,Σ,Σ,,1))

OR
=let(Σ,InvoicingPeriods!A3:A,+filter(Σ,Σ>today()))



Thank you very much, this is exactly what we were looking for
